# Viewing users in django admin

Tags: python, django

I extended my user model to create two profile types, a mentor profile and a student profile. However I am noticing that I cannot view any of my users in django.admin. I only see groups under authentication.

Here is my admin.py file

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .forms import TeacherSignUpForm, StudentSignUpForm
from .models import Student, Mentor

class CustomerUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_mentor_form = TeacherSignUpForm
    add_student_form = StudentSignUpForm
    mentor_model = Mentor
    student_model = Student

admin.site.register(Mentor, Student, CustomerUserAdmin)
```

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_activated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
...
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Profile of user{}".format(self.user.username)
class Mentor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='mentor')
    linkedin = models.URLField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='media', default='default.jpg')
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    billing_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    account_num = models.IntegerField(default=1234)
    bank_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    branch_code = models.IntegerField(default=1234)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Profile of user {}".format(self.user.username)
...
```

forms.py

```
class TeacherSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=100)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    linkedin = forms.URLField(max_length=200)
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=500)
    billing_name = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    account_num = forms.IntegerField()
    bank_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    branch_code = forms.IntegerField()
...
class StudentSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=100)
```

Currently when I try and run makemigrations after creating admin.py I get the error message:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: classroom
```

As requested here is settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.humanize',
'crispy_forms',
'classroom',
'classroom.apps.ClassroomConfig',
]
```

Just to explain the structure of my project. I have 3 views, teachers, students and classroom. The classroom view deals with the home pages and pages that can be viewed by any visitor (you don't need to be logged in), teachers= teacher profile pages and students = student profile pages

Not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: Seems to be related to your directory layout or such, doesn't have anything to do with admin. You probably get the same just running 'check' or 'runserver' instead of 'makemigrations'. Could you summarize all 'classroom' references instead?

Comment: add your `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: @NalinDobhal Just added my installed_apps

Comment: @Macke I have added a bit more detail. As a side note the error only arose after I created admin.py and added classroom.apps.Classroomconfig to m settings.py, removing this returns the error message  admin.site.register takes only 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Comment: in your installed apps, you are adding a duplicate entry for app `classroom`, either remove `classroom` or remove `classroom.apps.ClassroomConfig`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nalin Dobhal nailed it:

> in your installed apps, you are adding a duplicate entry for app
>   classroom, either remove classroom or remove
>   classroom.apps.ClassroomConfig